# MySQL makes my site load very slow

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to find what the problem is.

My homepage takes 5s to load and I suspected highly its because of MySQL. when I type my site url in the browser, I have to wait 5s only then it will load.

I have dedicated server running intel celeron, centos with 1GB RAM. My database is approx 650mb in size with 200k records and i have index created for date,id etc.

Here is my SQL query used in the homepage:

```
select `id`,`title`,`desc`,`contribution`,`date`,`sponsored`                
from tbl_releases where date <= CURRENT_DATE()  AND approved='1' 
order by `date` desc,`sponsored` desc,`con` desc,`id` desc
limit 100
```

I tried every everything like

1. optimizing using my.cnf with buffer etc but its not improving the site performance.
2. optimizing table.

P.S: does database size have impact on performance? I have over 50% junk in database and does deleting useless rows help improve the performance?

---

update: i did cleanup junk in the database and the performance improved dramatically and i noticed that server load and mysql cpu usage has gone significantly down from 36% to just 5% . But still what i dont understand, is why is mysql is slowing down on such large data, it should pretty much handle that much data. isnt it?

Btw, i am using smarty engine, despite this, site is slowing down.

Comment: 50% of 200k records is too much garbage ! Still if you are not able to lower load time why dont u make this Ajax and show a loader icon

Comment: @pbu so if you take this query out, it loads faster? MySQL can handle large databases, so it may not be optimized that way it needs to be. Do you have any indexes on that table?

Comment: You have no space between the SELECT and the id`, also some other syntax errors. Are you sure this is the query you have on your home page? Because that would fail.

Comment: i do have index created, but not seeing any improvement in site loading speed. thanks

Answer (score 7):

Well there are many reasons why your site could be slow.

- Bad queries
- Improper indexes in database
- Lot of images
- Large images
- Lot of scripts
  and may others

MySQL may be one reason, so make sure to clean up your database, create proper indexes, use Memcache, etc. Also analyse your select queries using [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-explain.html)

[Here](https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/optimizing-websites/) is an article written by me on optimizing websites.

Answer (score 2):

A few ideas:

I doubt you need to run that query *every* time. Cache the data into a static file that you include on the home page. Regenerate the file periodically or when the data changes.

Adding indexes for the columns used in the `WHERE` clause could massively improve `SELECT` time (at the expense of slowing down `INSERT`s). If you already have indexes, use the `EXPLAIN SELECT` command to make sure it's using them.

650 MB for 200k rows makes if wonder if you're storing, perhaps(?), thumbnails in that table. If so, that could explain it. Databases are optimized for lots of tiny pieces of data. File systems are optimized for a smaller number of larger chunks of data. You would get better performance if any large blobs of data could be migrated to files.

Actually, if I'm reading it right, you haven't confirmed that the time is spent in the database at all. Sprinkle benchmarks in your code to track down where the time is going. Use `$_start = microtime(1);` and `echo "Done in " . number_format(microtime(1) - $_start, 2) . " seconds.<br>";` at the beginning and end of the script or at the beginning and end of suspect parts.

Answer (score 1):

Well, how long does the query take when you run it from the CLI?

I'd be surprised if it is in fact your database.  200K rows is just not that big.

Queries time will increase with the log of the size of the time if the query has proper indices; linearly otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

using [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)Memcache will help to improve the performance of your server

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the results into TABLE, internet explorer -at least for some versions- renders it slow. Have you tried  other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

"I suspected highly its because of MySQL"

Knowing > suspecting.

So measure it! Use Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to measure page-speed.

1. how long does the query take when done on the command line? Too long --> optimize it
2. how heavy is the page you're loading? (use Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools) --> too heavy? Use YSlow [these guidelines](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/help/).
3. Put your page content as static files on your server, load that, is it significantly faster, then it's the code generating the content. Use server-side caching like memcache.
4. Still not fast enough? Try using a different webserver like Nginx or something.

About number 4: that's pretty high tech. First get the "lower-hanging fruit".